# Replacing Escape characters with other characters in scala

Tags: regex, string, scala, replace

I wanted to replace the escape character \" from the string i receive from my Scala code and replace with ". Any thoughts

my code

```
customtextcolumn.toString().replaceAll("\"", "")

customtextcolumn = {\"textdata\":\"this is the custom data to be printed in the text\",\"textalignment\":\"center\",\"pageheight\":\"12\",\"pagewidth\":\"8\"}
```

The Text string I except to have is

```
{"textdata":"this is the custom data to be printed in the text","textalignment":"center","pageheight":"12","pagewidth":"8"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`replace` works, you don't need Regex:

```
customtextcolumn.replace("""\"""", """""""")
```

I also used `"""` so you don't have to escape `"`.

Or with escaping:

```
customtextcolumn.replace("\\\"", "\"")
```

I tested this with:

```
val customtextcolumn = """{\"textdata\":\"this is the custom data to be printed in the text\",\"textalignment\":\"center\",\"pageheight\":\"12\",\"pagewidth\":\"8\"}"""
```